# Need help with SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-tasks-list

I am working on SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflows and want to do the following task: -

1: Without user intervention, when the change start date/time is reached, notify a person that the change outcome needs to be updated.

2: Without user intervention, -  remind the group to completed if ANY of the the "Change Outcome", "Change Outcome Notes", "Change Completed Date"   are not filled in, then they all need to be completed.

Can someone tell me the statements to use in the both situations, as I am new to the SharePoint designer 2013.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way that I have created a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow and the workflow worked as: On update of list - > do any action (Optional) - > then pause until start date/time - > If "change outcome" or "change outcome notes" or "Change Completed Date" is empty -> then email (Specify people and email message).

That's it.

I hope it will help a lot of people.